# How to group elements to add amounts in array with Vue JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list that I get from an axios call, what I try is to create an array where the products that have the same id, increase the amount and subtotal for that product, otherwise they will be added with the amount as it is.

but I always get quantity = 1.xx and a wrong total, I do not understand why or where the fault can be

```
 let dataGroup = [];


 resp.data.forEach((element)=>{
    let indexElement  = dataGroup.findIndex(elm => {
        return (elm.product_id === element.product_id ) && element.print;
    });
    if(indexElement !== -1){
        dataGroup[indexElement].total +=  parseFloat(element.total);
        dataGroup[indexElement].count +=  parseInt(element.count);
        roundNumber(dataGroup[indexElement].count,0);
        roundNumber(dataGroup[indexElement].total,2);
    }
    else{
        dataGroup.push(element);
    }
});
```

Function

```
window.roundNumber = function(num, scale) {
  if(!("" + num).includes("e")) {
      return +(Math.round(num + "e+" + scale)  + "e-" + scale);
  } else {
      var arr = ("" + num).split("e");
      var sig = ""
      if(+arr[1] + scale > 0) {
      sig = "+";
      }
      return +(Math.round(+arr[0] + "e" + sig + (+arr[1] + scale)) + "e-" + scale);
  }
}
```

dataGroup in the first instance is empty, everything works according to the data I receive from my call with axios, for example in the image the first row I must get 9 in quantity but I receive that 1.00, the unit value is 35 should be 9 * 53 in ST, but it's not like that

[image]

Response for axios

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "product_id": 1,
        "count": "1.00",
        "total": "35.00",
        "print": 1
    },
    {    
       "id": 5,
        "product_id": 1,
        "count": "1.00",
        "total": "35.00",
        "print": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "product_id": 1,
        "count": "1.00",
        "total": "35.00",
        "print": 1
    }
 ....
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo in JSFiddle or else? provide demo data of `dataGroup` array, `element.print`, etc.?

Comment: @SajibKhan dataGroup in the first instance is empty, everything works according to the data I receive from my call with axios, for example in the image the first row I must get 9 in quantity but I receive that 1.00, the unit value is 35 should be 9 * 53 in ST, but it's not like that

Comment: can you provide `resp.data` demo data?

Comment: @SajibKhan I added a base example of what the axios request gets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some logical issues. Check this (see comments in code):

```js
resp.data.forEach((element)=>{
  let indexElement  = dataGroup.findIndex(elm => {
    return (elm.product_id === element.product_id ) && element.print;
  });
  if(indexElement !== -1){
    // first convert total/count to float/int then update in existing array element
    dataGroup[indexElement].total += roundNumber(parseFloat(element.total), 0);
    dataGroup[indexElement].count += roundNumber(parseInt(element.count), 2);
  }
  else {
    // need to convert total/count to float/int then push to dataGroup
    element.total = roundNumber(parseFloat(element.total), 0);
    element.count = roundNumber(parseInt(element.count), 2);

    dataGroup.push(element);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it was that, what a mistake! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way you're initializing the items in the group. String values are returned from the server and then you're trying to add them to floats. Try running this through your console.

```
"35.00" + parseFloat("35.00")
```

To solve this issue, you must first initialize the value as a float. Instead of this:

```
dataGroup.push(element)
```

Try this:

```
dataGroup.push({
        id: element.id,
        product_id: element.product_id,
        total: parseInt(element.total),
        count: parseFloat(element.count),
        print: !!element.print,
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_cole/wr5jk8o4/6/)